# Vote arrow stays lit even if voting on the post wasn't allowed (own post, deleted/locked post, not enough rep, etc.)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting

**This is not a duplicate of [After voting on a post, I'm unable to change that vote until I refresh the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365064/after-voting-on-a-post-im-unable-to-change-that-vote-until-i-refresh-the-page) as that issue is with *retracting* votes, not *casting* votes, and I don't see any console error messages here unlike there. This bug seems to have a different cause from that bug.**

I just tried to downvote an answer on a site where I don't have the required 125 reputation to downvote. The score remained at 0, and I got the right error message, but the downvote arrow still remained lit:

[image: Unsuccessful downvote on answer, but arrow is still lit]

Previously, the arrow would stop lighting up after the unsuccessful vote and error message, but in this case, it still continues to be lit. Refreshing the page clears it.

I was also able to reproduce this with both upvotes and downvotes on one of my own posts, which I can't vote on regardless of rep, and on deleted and locked posts. The same is also very likely to occur with upvotes for users who don't have the required 15 rep, but I didn't try to reproduce that.

Using Firefox 88 ([supported](//browsers.stackoverflow.design/)) on Ubuntu 20.04. Am also able to reproduce on modern Microsoft Edge on Windows.

Comment: Reproed on Firefox 78 esr, also works with posts that have a score above 0. The score flicks one down, and then back to its original state, showing the error message and the highlighted arrow.

Comment: I don't think it should stay lit no matter what. I only support acknowledging post feedback in a way that makes it clear that it's not a real vote (consider the case of someone who crosses the threshold to gain or even lose a voting privilege.)

Comment: @Mureinik Not a duplicate. That issue is with *retracting* votes, not *casting* votes. I also don't see any console error messages here unlike there. That bug seems to be a different cause.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog fair enough, retracted.

Comment: Two headed regression monster attacked. Yaakov slashed one, one still remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Illegal vote de-highlight restored

> you know how it goes:
> stomp on one bug, and two more
> rise up in its place