# After voting on a post, I'm unable to change that vote until I refresh the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

After upvoting or downvoting on any post, question or answer, I can't change it. I can replicate this on both MSE and MSO. In the console, I'm getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: newScore is not defined

After which the button appears to be focused. Reloading returns things to normal until I vote again.

Comment: Well, I upvoted to test this and can't unupvote, so I guess it's staying ;)

Comment: Note that it's not just un-voting, but re-voting at all– I can't correct my upvote to a downvote (or vice versa) without refreshing either.

Comment: Sounds like we've identified the issue here but we're not going to have a fix out immediately since it's the end of the day.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is fixed across the network.

> this one is on me
> silly regression error
> feel free to test here

Comment: Is this related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365059/vote-arrow-stays-lit-even-if-voting-on-the-post-wasnt-allowed-own-post-delete

Comment: yes, but separate issue

Answer (score 6):

I can replicate this [on Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10689). It's even worse than you've stated already: during a First Posts review, if a vote is the only action that was required the radiobutton won't move from "No action needed" to "I'm Done" unless you hit F5 (this is also the workaround to be able to remove your vote again).

Before F5:
[image: No action needed]

After F5:
[image: I'm done]

This may sound like something minor, but this means our review histories are now incorrect. Which has all kinds of unfortunate side-effects, since it's much harder to find out now if people are using the First Posts queue wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this can also be done on deleted posts
I just “downvoted” a deleted post (one that said “this post was recently deleted and is no longer viewable”), and the downvote icon stuck, without changing the displayed score, and still displaying the error message. I couldn’t “undownvote.”

Comment: Wrong bug. [This bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365059/vote-arrow-stays-lit-even-if-vote-didnt-succeed-due-to-lack-of-required-privile?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the one you're referring to.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog my bad, I didn’t notice that one.